# Streaming Upload to AmazonS3 with boto or simples3 API

Tags: amazon-s3, python-2.7, boto

Is boto API (python) for amazons3 is streaming upload? 
there is another API called Simples3. i think no body is heard of it.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simples3

it has a function call for streaming upload. but i would like to use boto if it has streaming upload option.

i know about Multipart in Boto. i dont want to use multipart because i do not want to split the files on disk and have one huge file and splits of it. i believe it's a wastage of space.

What would be the difference between boto and simples3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "streaming upload" you mean chunked transfer encoding, then I don't think boto, simples3 or any other package will support it because S3 doesn't support it.  Boto has methods for streaming but they are only supported by Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Then what is [simples3](http://sendapatch.se/projects/simples3/streaming.html) claims to have implemented. this link gives simples3 api to upload with streaming(chunked transfer),it's built on another package called Poster. is it false ?

Comment: It looks like they are using the term "streaming" to describe an upload process where the bytes are read from the file and uploaded to S3 incrementally rather than reading the entire file into memory.  This is different than chunked transfer encoding, as supported by Google Cloud Storage, where the Content-Length header is not needed.  Boto automatically uses this type of "streaming" upload whenever you use the set_content_from_file or set_content_from_filename methods.