# Writing bytes stream to s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I have a zip file loaded into memory (do not have it persisted on disk).  The zip file contains jpg images.  I am trying to upload each jpg into s3 but am getting an error.

```
# already have an opened zipfile stored in zip_file
# already connected to s3

files = zip_file.namelist()

for f in files:
    im = io.BytesIO(zip_file.read(f))
    s3_key.key = f
    s3_key.set_contents_from_stream(im)
```

I get the following error:

> BotoClientError: BotoClientError: s3 does not support chunked transfer

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060479)

Comment: @goncalopp ahh.  I do not want to save the image first to disk, how does one upload a file in memory to s3? - thx

Comment: Do you know the size of the data?  S3 does not supported chunked encoding so you must supply a correct ``ContentLength`` header in the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution.  I was over thinking the problem.

```
files = zip_file.namelist()

for f in files:
    data = zip_file.read(f)
    s3_key._key.key = f
    s3_key._key.set_contents_from_string(data)
```

That's all it took.

Answer (score 2):

Boto supports other storage services, such as Google Cloud Storage, in addition to S3. The set_contents_from_stream method only works for services that support chunked transfer (see https://codereview.appspot.com/4515170). S3 does not support that (See their Technical FAQs at http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109.)

It's unfortunate, but you can't upload from a stream to S3.

Comment: hmmm, that seems like a serious limitation, being forced to save image to disk before uploading to s3.  Is that correct, I cannot save an image to s3 from memory?

Comment: You can use set_contents_from_string if all your data is in a string in memory.

Comment: Ahh, since I have jpgs in memory, what is the recommended way in python to write them to s3 as an jpg file using set_contents_from_string? thx.